# Testing Python API which uses MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, testing, flask

Im working on a Python API which uses MongoDB and Flask-PyMongo.
My APP gets the MONGO_URI (also on testing).

I don't want to use the production database on software tests.
I want a mongo container which i can start with python before the test starts or just a library which can mock the pymongo library.

Im on a windos platform, most existing libraries which i found doesn't work properly. I already tested mockupdb and InstantMongo.

On APIs with SQL i can use in-memory SQLite in tests and in production i can use the regular SQL server. Is there a similar approach for MongoDB? (I have to use mongodb and can't switch to sql)

Comment: This can help you: [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/)

Comment: This is only for enterprise edition.... :(